# Improving "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, migration

On closing panel in stackoverflow there is the following form:

[image]

Sometimes I find questions, that are more suitable for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) or [drupal.stackexchange.com](http://drupal.stackexchange.com), but I can't vote for migration there, using this panel. So I have to raise a flag: "it needs ♦ moderator attention", and write: "belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com".

Is it possible to allow voting for migration to the other sites of stackexchange network?

Comment: Technically, yes, it is _possible_. But in terms of UI and UX, not so much. Additionally, some former targets for migration have requested to be removed (Programmmers for instance), as the quality of migrated questions was low and many migrations were being rejected.