# Automatically detect and dynamically build the list for offtopic migration options

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, migration, off-topic

Questions on Stack Overflow has only 5 options when closing as off-topic when the question "belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network":

> Close ->
> A community-specific reason ->
> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

I see a suggestion to add more options ([Improving "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190993/197674)) and I understand why this proposal was rejected.

But I'm suggesting to not change the amount of options but choose them depending on the question's tags and title.

e.g. this question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/69717892/1723695) is clearly about Ubuntu and Linux and question's tags says that. But when I click "close" to move it to another site, it shows me irrelevant Stack Exchange sites: Tex, DBA, Stats. It'd be correct to show here sites like Ask Ubuntu, Unix and Super User here.

Comment: This could be really cool - but I don't see us ever building it - at least not any time soon. What you're asking for is extremely complex and we are very strict about how and when we set up migration targets. This is why we only allow a few choices - not because they are the only options but because if we make some options too easy, bad content can be migrated without people understanding the target site's scope. If U&L doesn't want a pipeline to SO, your proposal isn't going to solve *that* problem. I'd recommend you consider this and see if you can adjust your proposal somewhat?

Comment: Good idea, which was suggested before.